# power bi: combine multiple tables into one

Tags: powerbi

In Power BI, I am creating a report with some finance data of a company. I have 3 different tables. The table structure of all three tables are as follows:
[image]

I want to change these tables into this structure:

[image]
Is it possible to achieve this kind of structure? If yes and please suggest some method to do this?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. What's not possible is that we write the code for you. Get started, and when you get stuck, post what code you have so far and why you are stuck.

Comment: @teylyn I am not asking for whole code. Just some heads up for where to start from?

Comment: @teylyn can you suggest something how to start doing  this?? Need some advice please.

Comment: Start with a Power Query tutorial.

Comment: Did you ask this question and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46342340/power-bi-combine-multiple-tables-into-one) for the same purpose? If so, then I presume this has been answered to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

To do it simply you can import 3 times your table using the query editor, and then in one table keep only columns for Planned, in the second table keep columns for Actual, and so on...

Hope that helps!

Comment: All the three tables are different. How these can be imported into one table.

Comment: In your question you say the table structure of all three tables is the same as the first screenshot. Now you say it's different. How much more of your mind do you expect us to read?

Comment: Data of three table is different

Comment: If you have 3 data source and you want to merge them you should use the merge function in the query editor, this will merge all columns with the same name and append those with different names.