# Power bi: combine multiple tables into one

Tags: powerbi

I have three tables whose structure is as follows-

Table 1-

[image]

Table 2-

[image]

Table 3-

[image]

I wanted to have a table like this -

[image]

I tried this particular formula for creating a calculated table-

```
Table = UNION(SELECTCOLUMNS(Table1,"Table1", Tables[Table1]), SELECTCOLUMNS(Table2, "Table2 Totals", Table2[Totals]), SELECTCOLUMNS(Table3, "Table3 Totals", Table3[Totals]))
```

The result I am getting is like this:-

[image]

I have no idea why this is happening. What to do in this scenario? Do calculated columns not come in merge query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create 2 new tables and then join them based on Table1 Column1.

The 2 new tables I would create are inner joins of 
NewTable1: Table1 Col2 and Table2 Col1
NewTable2: Table1 Col3 and Table3 Col1

Afterwards, create merge queries as new on Table1Col1 and NewTable1
Then one more time with NewTable2.

Let me know if you'd like me to clear it up, hoping the process is explained well enough to give a general idea/direction.

Comment: I tried this but the issue is coming when one of the table contains calculated columns and calculated columns are not appearing in merge/append query.

Comment: They should be appearing.  Your result looks halfway there as well. Are you doing it via code or the step by step process in PowerBI

Comment: Just managed to do it. My calculated total columns are in excel.